# Windows 10 Bluetooth causing random reboot of devices

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I am using Windows 10, and I'm not sure what changed other than my laptop recently received some updates. Despite those updates, it is still running version 1803 (build 17134), and I am experiencing issues with my Samsung Level U Pro headset. When I connect the headset to my laptop via Bluetooth, the headset reboots randomly and frequently. This is an issue that I do not experience while using the headset with my phone.

My laptop is a Dell XPS 9570 with Intel AC Wi-Fi 9260. The Bluetooth driver version is 20.90.1.1 (I updated it 2 days ago), and the Wi-Fi driver version is 20.90.0.7. Any ideas on how to make this stop?

Comment: Have you tried rolling the BT driver back to a previous version?  What updates did your machine receive?  What cumulative update are you running?  Use `winver` to determine that information.  When the device worked which driver did you have installed?  Instead of submitting comments, please, edit your question.  [Download](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/99445/Intel-Wireless-AC-9260) several previous versions, does this problem, with all of them.  Update your question to indicate which versions you tried.

Comment: Try to check if the system build-in bluetooth driver works well on your computer after uninstall the existing driver and reboot computer to load a new one. As windows update will also update devices drivers at the same time, we also could check with the PC manufacturer bluetooth driver and your headset driver if it has with the lastest version. If the issue persists, try to reset system and re-connect it again.